# SQL Server not accessible after renaming

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to rename a SQL Server instance after I installed it. I am using SQL Server 2017 Developer edition.

After the installation, I changed the name and restarted the server using the Configuration Manager, but when I go to the Object Explorer and try to connect, a server with that name was not available. When I select the server name, it is there.

```
 sp_dropserver 'MI1234'

 sp_addserver 'MSSQLSERVER01','local'

 SELECT @@SERVERNAME
```

Comment: Generally, if you *do* need to change the instance name you are better off reinstalling the instance.

Comment: I would do that, but when I was installing it I never got asked to choose a name.

Comment: It's definitely part of the set up. I suspect you missed the point at which you got to choose your instance name (which by default is `MSSQLSERVER`).

Comment: Unless, of course, you're using SQL Server on Linux, as I recall that only uses the default name. I doubt this though, as you reference the Configuration Manager; which isn't available on Linux.

Comment: Did you rename that server as well or maybe create an alias for the instance so that your instance name will match your server IP and port?